# List item loses styling when added dynamically

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the latest version of `Bootstrap` for the styling of most of my HTML elements.

On one of my pages I need to dynamically add list items to my `<ul></ul>` element. I am adding these additional list items with `jQuery`. This is how I do it:

```
$('ul.test-items').append('<li class="available">Test Item</li><li class="available">Test Item</li>');');
```

After a new list item is added to the ul element it seems to lose the styling just for that `<li></li>` item, the already added list items display correctly. The list items have padding on either side of them, but when added they seems to be added next to each other, with no padding. Do I need to redraw the ul element after adding new list items to it so that it can be styled as part of the ul element?

It seems to work well for adding 1 list item element, but 2 or more you can see the difference.

This is my current HTML markup:

```
<ul class="list-inline test-items">
     <li class="available">product colour 1</li>
     <li class="available">product colour 3</li>
</ul>
```

After adding the new list items via jQuery it looks like this:

```
<ul class="list-inline test-items">
     <li class="available">product colour 1</li>
     <li class="available">product colour 3</li>
     <li class="available">Test Item</li>
     <li class="available">Test Item</li>
</ul>
```

When I view the markup by pressing `F12` in `Chrome` it looks right, it's just not displaying right. My guess is it is not part of the already styled ul element.

Here is my style:

```
.test-items .available
{
    border: 2px solid #999;
}
```

Comment: can you please reproduce this on http://jsfiddle.net ? because it seems to be working fine here http://jsbin.com/hemiye/edit?html,js,output

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0s7n3907/ it seems working fine

Comment: It works fine for adding 1 list item element, trying adding 2 or more. Also see my style class for adding a border around each list item element.

Comment: `$('ul.test-items').append('$('ul.test-items').append('<li…` – that code just makes no sense. Did you edit this in now by mistake, or is that your actual code? (Probably not, that should not even work, due to syntax errors.)

Comment: @CBroe Sorry my mistake, check it out now.

Comment: Still unclear what the actual problem is though – again, seems to work fine, see https://jsfiddle.net/0s7n3907/2/ // If bootstrap plays into this somehow, then please provide a test page (fiddle or sth. else), where we can see _that_.

Comment: @CBroe It no use you add your own stuff. Use the Bootstrap files and let me know what your findings are. I can also go and just add the elements like you did and it will work. The question is using it with Bootstrap. The same goes for @Dhiraj!

Comment: @Why was there a negative vote on this question? The people responding are only replicating half of the problem without bootstrap, which obviously works. Do it with Bootstrap and let me know the results!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> The list items have padding on either side of them, but when added they seems to be added next to each other, with no padding

Padding is *inside* the element – and the newly added elements have that padding *inside* of their borders as well. That is not the issue.

The spacing *between* the elements, that comes only from the whitespace between the element’s tags – because the `li` are displayed `inline`.

If *that’s*  what you are after here – then you simply have to add that whitespace between the newly added elements yourself:

```
.append('<li class="available">Test Item</li> <li class="available">Test Item 2</li>');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0s7n3907/4/

Comment: For the 3rd time now add Bootstap then show me your results!

Comment: Adding a space between `<li></li>` and `<li></li>` will not solve the problem!

Comment: 1. That fiddle _does_ include bootstrap! (And it would rather have been _your_ job to provide such an example in the first place.) 2. The first list in that example is with your code, the `li` directly after each other, whereas the second one _does_ have whitespace between the `li` – are you telling me that you see no difference in the results …?

Comment: If you’re saying this _doesn’t_ solve your problem (and the downvote wasn’t just a pretty “revenge” one) – then you might need to be more specific know about what your problem actually is … My code as shown _does_ have the same spacing between the newly added elements as the already existing ones – so if that’s not what you are asking about – then _what is_?

Comment: I don't understand why there needs to be a space? It doesn't make sense. What happens if you minify your HTML then you will sit with the same problem.

Comment: Because the list items are displayed as `inline-block`, and that means without whitespace between the tags they are laid out directly next to each other. Of course you don’t need to rely on that, and can create spacing between them via a `margin` instead. Although then you might want to eliminate the whitespace around the first two, already existing items, otherwise you will still get inconsistent spacing if the next ones are appended without such a space before/after them. For that, see https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: I see what you mean. I did my own little test. Your solution works :)